# Узнавание мак адреса компьютера в локальной сети с помощью программных методов

Tags: c#, сетевое-программирование, mac-address

Есть небольшой код, захватывает девайс, формируем ARP пакет, шлём запрос и ответ засовываем в переменную, и именно с этим у меня возникла проблема, так как метод все время возвращает `null`

```
LibPcapLiveDevice device = devices[DeviceComboBoxList.SelectedIndex];
ARP resolve = new ARP(device);
resolve.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
PhysicalAddress resolvedMacAddress = new ARP(device).Resolve(ipD);
if (resolvedMacAddress != null) {
    MessageBox.Show(resolvedMacAddress.ToString());
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("returned null");
}
```

Однако при просмотре пакетов с помощью программы wireshark, они там есть, в т.ч. и ответ от запрашиваемого. Для тех кто умеет работать с библиотекой, подскажите, что не так, или дайте альтернативный метод решения. Win10 64x, версия SharpPcap - 4.2.0
[image: WireShark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно получить MAC-адрес с помощью функции SendARP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {        

        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, [Out] byte[] pMacAddr, ref int PhyAddrLen);

        public static string GetMacByIp(IPAddress ip)
        {

            byte[] ab = new byte[6];
            int len = ab.Length;
            int r = SendARP((int)ip.Address, 0, ab, ref len);
            if (r != 0) throw new ApplicationException("SendARP failed with code " + r.ToString());
            return BitConverter.ToString(ab, 0, 6);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");
            Console.WriteLine(GetMacByIp(ip));

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215788/8674428